# Как возвратить у метода тип объекта класса, в котором он находится?

Tags: java, ооп

```
class TaskList{
    public TaskList getTaskList(){
        ....
    }
}
```

*Вопрос: Как вернуть в методе* `getTaskList()` *объект с типом* `TaskList`? (Любым образом типа создания доп переменных и тд.) Спасибо.

Comment: `return this` не пробовали?

Comment: `public TaskList getTaskList(){
       retutn this;
    }` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для этих целей существует ключевое слово `this`. Оно является ссылкой на экземпляр класса в котором вызывается.

Таким образом любой нестатический метод любого класса, желающий, возвращать ссылку на класс из коего вызван должен возвращать `this`:

```
class TaskList{
    public TaskList getTaskList(){
        return this;
    }
}
```

**P.S.**

немного полезностей на англо-саксонском: [when-should-i-use-this-in-a-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411270/when-should-i-use-this-in-a-class)